A third party Chinese Character font is invisible on Word, but displays correctly on Pages - Sonoma 14.6.1
For work purposes I have to use a specific Chinese character font type called "Free HK Kai 4700" (自由香港楷書 (4700字)), which I downloaded via its official website (https://freehkfonts.opensource.hk/download/). When installing/validating there are two errors: 'name' table usability and 'name' table structure.

The characters appear properly in the Font Book itself.

The font appears on both Pages and Word. The font works correctly on Pages, like so:

However, on Word, despite being able to choose the font, the font is invisible/does not display:

Word documents with the "Free HK Kai" font will display when opened with Pages, but not on Word. Same Word document when opened with a Windows machine will correctly display characters typed using the font type.
I've tried removing the font from the Font Book and reinstalling, I've tried installing the font type using different sources, updating, restarting etc. However, no luck. Chinese font types available by default on macOS work properly, but not this font.
Any idea what the issue is?

Also try the Word forum if you have not already.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_unknown-mso_OPMac?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&isFilterExpanded=true&page=1
